# Separate string by comma and delete new line characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

I have a text file with a 6 line poem...

Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    reading = read_file();
    splitting = isUnique(reading);

def read_file():
    fp = open('BWA5.in','r'); #open file
    lines = fp.read(); #read file
    fp.close(); #close file
    return lines; #return lines to main function

def isUnique(lines):
    words = "";#creates blank string
    for i in lines:#convert list to string
        words += i;
    splitWords = words.split(",");
    print splitWords;


#def findUniqueChars():


#def write_file():


main();
```

After reading the text file, and performing the above code, all I get is an array with 1 element which is all the lines of the poem in that one element. However, I need each word within the poem separated by commas, with the new line characters taken out, as well as every single word as a single element so that I can search through the list and analyze each word by itself.

This is what it is outputting right now,
['Hey diddle diddle\nThe cat and the fiddle\nThe cow jumped over the moon\nThe little dog laughed\nTo see such sport\nAnd the dish ran away with the spoon']

But I need something like this,
['Hey', 'diddle', 'diddle', etc.] (with new line characters removed)

Comment: oh gosh, please remove the `;`.

Comment: We can't really help until we know how you read your file...

Comment: Can you share some sample input and the output you'd like to get for it?

Comment: edited again above

Comment: At a glance, it seems like `words += i` is concatenating all the letters together   You should do `words = line.strip().split(" ")` to get each word without newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This short complete program might do what you want:

```
with open('BWA5.in') as fp:
    words = fp.read().split()

print(words)
```

Output:

```
['Hey', 'diddle', 'diddle', 'The', 'cat', 'and', 'the', 'fiddle', 'The', 'cow', 'jumped', 'over', 'the', 'moon', 'The', 'little', 'dog', 'laughed', 'To', 'see', 'such', 'sport', 'And', 'the', 'dish', 'ran', 'away', 'with', 'the', 'spoon']
```